# How does iMacro Saves File In Same Name Instead Random or Custom

Tags: javascript, imacros

I tried saving a screenshot file from a website to my local folder but it goes null or stops when I try to replay the script.
For example: I want iMacros to save the file in random name.
The process of saving the screenshot is go to URL and click on the save screenshot but then right click on "Save image" link and click save link as.
[Sample Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzyrs.jpg)

Here is what I tried.

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://tradingview.binary.com/v1.2.20/main.html
FRAME NAME="tradingview_e12df"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:button<SP>getimage<SP>apply-common-tooltip&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:_tv-dialog-title-close&&TXT:
```

Comment: Why not to save screenshots by means of the [`SCREENSHOT` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/SCREENSHOT) ?

Comment: because I am not familiar with commands and so on but I tried firefox plugins but none of them worked for me. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `SCREENSHOT TYPE=Browser FOLDER=* FILE=*` . For more details check out the link I provided before.